# Lookbehind assertion needed?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of names like so:

```
[u'First Last', u' First', u' First', u' First'...]
```

or

```
[u'First M. Last', u' Last, u' Last'...]
```

or even

```
[u'First', u' First', u' First'...]
```

So there may be a full name,  followed by some number of single names. Note also the prefixed spacing on the latter items of each list. I want to extract only the single names, regardless of such spacing.

I am trying to ascertain whether a lookbehind assertion of some kind is the right way to do this. I'm having a hard time finding Python examples that seem like they might apply. The spacing is an artifact of earlier entity extraction via regex, which is possibly not optimal, but that's another question...

I'm not looking for code help since I know I'm not that far along; guidance would be awesome though! Is lookbehind what I'm looking for?

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far? Maybe trimming before attempting to match?

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract (i. e. what is a "single name")?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I believe it's every single word, and in the provided example implies `u' First'` or `u' Last'` or `u'First'` are what he's after, but not `u'First Last'` or `u'First M. Last'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably what you need, make sure to use the `UNICODE` flag, since you are using unicode strings `u''`:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^\s*([^\s]+)\s*$', re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this regex for taking single words:

```
^ *(\S+) *$
```

but you can be interested in looking letters only:

```
^ *([a-zA-Z]+) *$
```